# HTML pages resized

Tags: html, css, web

I am designing a web site currently.  So far there is a main page, about page, and blog page.  I copied all the code from the home page, which consisted only of the menu bar, to the other pages.  When I switch between pages the about and blog pages are resized slightly.  What is causing this.  They contain the exact code from the home page.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a link to the pages on live server for us to view?

Comment: It could have something to do with your browser's scroll bar.

Comment: Please provide with more information (such as screenshots, code, links, github etc)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem and I feel like a total noob.  I do my coding on my laptop and I used Firefox (initially) to check the code.  When working on the main page I zoomed in slightly.  I forgot that the zoom did not transfer between pages.  I made the zoom the same on all three pages and all is good.

Let this be a lesson kiddos,  the simplest solution is most of the time the correct one.